# Link url my site

Tags: php

I have a site with 2 languages that are En and kh. Each language has the same file name in different folder, i.e. /en/ and /th/. I've created  tag to switch between these 2 languages on my included header file (php).

The question is how to get the current path wherever you are, and change folder name to en or kh? (If you are inside English Contact page, clicking kh will take you to Thai Contact page.)

How to link this Language in my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Switch between the languages you will be first required to save user preference in cookies so next request will get selected language.

to render required file you can just compose the url/or load the language usin gcookie based information for lang

Answer (score 0):

Try and look into $_SERVER predefined values. Using this information you can work out the user current location and switch the language link accordingly.

A good place to start can be seen below.

`<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>`

More can be found at this link [Reserved Variables Server](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to find the path, str_replace to change en to kh and vice-versa and then redirect to your fresh new path :)

Comment: this will cause performance issue to redirect each time to next page

Comment: Well that is not what I had in mind. The redirection would have only occurred when switching language. Links between pages in one language would not have been recalculated at all... I you still think that would cause performance issues I would appreciate that you explain it to me a bit more